# Class attribute with value and callable methods

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I want to create a class with an attribute which can be called itself and return a value, and which can also call its own methods. The usage I want is like this:

```
f = CSVFile()
f.valid_transactions # returns a list of elements
f.valid_transactions.to_csv() # returns a string with csv format of the list
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried the following, but this way I need to use `f.valid_transactions()` (with brackets) instead of `f.valid_transactions` which is what I want

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from typing import List, Iterable, Mapping

from models.ValidTransaction import ValidTransaction

class CSVFile:
    class ValidTransactions:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            self._transactions: List[ValidTransaction] = []

        def __call__(self) -> List[ValidTransaction]:
            return self._transactions

        def __len__(self) -> int:
            return len(self._transactions)

        def to_csv(self):
            output = StringIO()
            header = ValidTransaction.get_output_header()
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output, header)
            writer.writeheader()
            
            for tx in self._transactions:
                writer.writerow(tx.dict())

            return output.getvalue()

    def __init__(self, rows: Iterable[Mapping]) -> None:
        self.valid_transactions: self.ValidTransactions = self.ValidTransactions()

        for row in rows:
            valid_tx = ValidTransaction(**row)
            self.valid_transactions._transactions.append(valid_tx)
```

Is this usage recommended, or for example should I code something like this instead:

```
f = CSVFile()
f.valid_transactions.get_value() # returns a list of elements
f.valid_transactions.to_csv() # returns a string with csv format of the list
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current approach?

Comment: Nothing but an usage preference. I would like to access the attribute as `f.valid_transactions` without having to call the class, as if it was an actual list instead of a class @a_guest

Comment: I don't see any problem with setting such a custom list class as an instance attribute. Note that there is [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) which helps in creating custom list classes.

Comment: Thank you @a_guest That `collections.UserList` class made to trick for what I wanted to achieve, as well as provide me with all the list native attributes and methods

Answer (score 0):

Final approach, using @a_guest `collections.UserList` recommendation on comments:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from collections import UserList
from typing import Iterable, Mapping

from pydantic import ValidationError

from models.ValidTransaction import ValidTransaction

class CSVFile:
    class ValidTransactions(UserList):
        def to_csv(self) -> str:
            output = StringIO()
            header = ValidTransaction.get_output_header()
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output, header)
            writer.writeheader()
            
            for tx in self.data:
                writer.writerow(tx)

            return output.getvalue()

    def __init__(self, rows: Iterable[Mapping]) -> None:
        self.valid_transactions: CSVFile.ValidTransactions = self.ValidTransactions()
        
        for row in rows:
            valid_tx = ValidTransaction(**row)
            self.valid_transactions.append(valid_tx.dict())
```

This way I can perform both actions I asked for:

```
f = CSVFile()
f.valid_transactions # returns a list of elements
f.valid_transactions.to_csv() # returns a string with csv format of the list
```